# Regex search in Symfony's expression language.

Tags: php, symfony, substring, expression

I'm trying to find an example where you use Symfony's ExpressionLanguage to do some kind of substring search, like the equivalent of something in Perl like:

```
$variableName =~ /word/;
```

Does anyone know how to do this, or any substring search in Symfony using the ExpressionLanguage class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$language->evaluate('"String word" matches "/word/"');
```

Comment: My problem is that it's looping through a number of expressions, i.e.  approved == 1, completed == 0, moneyAmount > 300, using the Symfony ExpressionLanguage->evaluate function.  I don't want to have to switch out and do a php strpos or preg_match.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: Hi PizzaLover, does that make more sense now?

Comment: maybe it will help you: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html#comparison-operators.